# Как решить эту задачу?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Добрый день решил изучить алгоритмы и делаю задачи из книги , но вот  с этой задачей сломал голову 
Условия

```
Имеется n пользователей, каждому из них соответствует список email-ов (всего у всех пользователей m email-ов).
Например:
user1 -> xxx@ya.ru, foo@gmail.com, lol@mail.ru
user2 -> foo@gmail.com, ups@pisem.net
user3 -> xyz@pisem.net, vasya@pupkin.com
user4 -> ups@pisem.net, aaa@bbb.ru
user5 -> xyz@pisem.net

Считается, что если у двух пользователей есть общий email, значит это один и тот же пользователь. Требуется построить
и реализовать алгоритм, выполняющий слияние пользователей. На выходе должен быть список пользователей с их email-ами (такой же как на входе).
Возможный ответ на задачу в указанном примере:
user1 -> xxx@ya.ru, foo@gmail.com, lol@mail.ru, ups@pisem.net, aaa@bbb.ru
user3 -> xyz@pisem.net, vasya@pupkin.com
условие требует решения за ,близкое к линейному время
```

Вроде легко я написал нечто такое

```
public class User {
    private String mName;
    private List<String> mAdress;

    public User(String mName,List<String>mAdress) {
        this.mName=mName;
        this.mAdress = mAdress;
    }

    public List<String> getmAdress() {
        return mAdress;
    }

    public void setmAdress(List<String> mAdress) {
        this.mAdress = mAdress;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add("asnjvkn@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("sfaf@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("asnjvkn@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("asnjvkn@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("cxv@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("asnjvkn@mail.ru");
        arrayList.add("vxcv@mail.ru");
        User user  = new User("user1",arrayList);
        ArrayList arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
        arrayList2.add("cxz@mail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("sfaxzvzf@mail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("asnjvkn@mail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("xv@mail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("cxv@mail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("asnjvkn@mvxail.ru");
        arrayList2.add("vxzvcv@mail.ru");
        User user2  = new User("user2",arrayList2);
        ArrayList arrayList3 = new ArrayList();
        arrayList3.add("sd@mail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("sfsdvaxzvzf@mail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("vd@mail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("xv@mail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("dsdvvs@mail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("asnjvkn@mvxail.ru");
        arrayList3.add("vxzvcv@mail.ru");
       User user3  = new User("user3",arrayList3);
       List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
       userList.add(user);
       userList.add(user2);
       userList.add(user3);

       userIdentification(userList);

    }



    public static void  userIdentification(List<User> userList){
     List<User> identifiedUser = new ArrayList<>();
     for (User singleUser: userList){
         for (int i = 0; i<singleUser.getmAdress().size();i++){
             for(User idenUser: identifiedUser){
              if (idenUser.getmAdress().contains(singleUser.getmAdress().get(i))){
                  System.out.println("true");
              }else{
                  System.out.println("false");
              }
             }
         }

     }

    }



}
```

но условие требует решения за ,близкое к линейному время 
Голову сломал подскажите как такое реализовать

Comment: Используйте коллекцию Set

Comment: Почему в ответе user1 и user3, а не, например, user2 и user5?

Comment: @Suvitruf мне кажется, что это не принципиально (сказано, что "возможный ответ")

Comment: В чем заключается задача?

Comment: Поиск компонент связности двудольного графа. Ищите и обрящете :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Правильный ответ, предложенный Harry**

> Имеем по сути двудольный граф. Задача - поиск его компонент связности.
>   Задача решается за линейное время от суммы числа вершин и числа ребер
>   (та самая почти линейность) тем же поиском в глубину.

**Оригинальный ответ**

Для хранения email-ов используйте коллекцию типа `Set`

А потом как-то так (псевдокод)

```
ArrayList<User> out = ArrayList();

for(i=0;i<users.size;i++){
    for(j=0;j<out.size;j++){
        if(!users[i].emails.disjoint(out[i]){
            out[i].emails.addAll(users[i].emails);
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    out.add(users[i]);
}
```

[Collection.disjoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29)

Простой перебор пользователей - это O(n), можно считать нижней границей. Далее на каждую итерацию основного цикла, в худшем случае, идет перебор последовательно увеличивающегося выходного списка, т.е. {O(1), O(2), O(3)...,O(n)}. Совокупно, этот алгоритм ограничен сверху O(n*log(n)). Допускаю, что обработку каждого пользователя можно свести к O(1), но не вижу путей, как этого достичь. Сложность операции сравнения двух наборов Set не учитываю, так как не знаю ее реализации.

Comment: но тут скорость будет далека от линейной

Comment: насамом деле условие требует )

Comment: близкое к On было

Comment: Log n  вот это время принимается

Comment: но ваш пример идет также в квадрат как и мое

Comment: @elik `log(n)` - это, на минуточку, лучше линейного и для данной задачи не достижимо в принципе. Мое решение не квадрат, а `n*log(n)`.

Comment: Во-первых, скажите линейное от чего? от числа емэйлов, юзеров? Юзеров n, у одного юзера m email'ов.
Во-вторых, для считывания и всего прочего уже нужно линейное время, о каком O(log n) идет речь? Или речь чисто об алгоритме и неважно за сколько сформированы структуры данных?

Comment: Я только намекну. Имеем по сути двудольный граф. Задача - поиск его компонент связности. Задача решается за линейное время от суммы числа вершин и числа ребер (та самая *почти* линейность) тем же поиском в глубину. И еще - не пишите O(2), O(3) - ну прямо неудобно получается как-то... :(

Comment: @Harry хм... А вот с такой стороны не догадался посмотреть :)  Это для наглядности

Answer (score 2):

Просто нужно знать коллекции:

```
public static Map<User, Set<String>> convert(List<User> input) {
    // первая тут будут уники мейлы и пользователь который последний добавил его
    Map<String, User> one = new HashMap<>();
    Map<User, Set<String>> two = new HashMap<>();

    // тут будут уники юзеры и мейлы из первой карты где он засветился с таким мейлом
    // выгружаем всех юзеров попорядку
    for (User user : input
    ) {
        User temp = user;
        // выгружаем каждого юзера почту по одной
        for (String email : user.getMails()
        ) {
            // если почты нет еще в
            if (!one.containsKey(email)) {
                // то добавляем почту и юзера
                one.put(email, temp);
            } else {
                // но если есть то всю почту этого юзера кидаем тому кто ее уже принеc
                one.get(email).getMails().addAll(temp.getMails());
                for (String mail2 : one.get(email).getMails()) {
                    one.putIfAbsent(mail2, one.get(email));
                }
                break;
            }
                two.put(one.get(email), one.get(email).getMails());
        }

    }
    return two;
}
```